# How to properly use win32gui.ReleaseDC and what does it do (python, pywin32)?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

I am new to this and I can't figure out which code is correct and fast?
All options are working, but then I can’t understand the difference in behavior, please help me figure it out. How does win32gui.ReleaseDC work and is it necessary to use it if everything works without it? Whether to delete objects.

**Examples of getting the color of a pixel:**

Variant #1

```
def get_pixel_rgb_color(self, pos: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[int, int, int]:
        rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self._hwnd)
        w = abs(rect[2] - rect[0])
        h = abs(rect[3] - rect[1])

        hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self._hwnd)
        mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
        saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
        saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)
        saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

        ret = win32gui.GetPixel(hwndDC, pos[0], pos[1])
        r, g, b = ret & 0xFF, (ret >> 8) & 0xFF, (ret >> 16) & 0xFF

        return r, g, b
```

Variant #2

```
def get_pixel_rgb_color(self, pos: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[int, int, int]:
        hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self._hwnd)

        ret = win32gui.GetPixel(hwndDC, pos[0], pos[1])
        r, g, b = ret & 0xFF, (ret >> 8) & 0xFF, (ret >> 16) & 0xFF

        return r, g, b
```

**Examples of area screenshot:**

Variant #1

```
def area_screenshot(self, start: Tuple[int, int], size: Tuple[int, int]) -> str:
        width, height = size[0], size[1]
        x_cord, y_cord = start[0], start[1]

        hwnd_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self._hwnd)
        mfc_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwnd_dc)
        dc_obj = mfc_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()
        bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfc_dc, width, height)

        dc_obj.SelectObject(bmp)
        dc_obj.BitBlt(
            (0, 0), (width, height), mfc_dc, (x_cord, y_cord), win32con.SRCCOPY
        )

        signed_ints_arr = bmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
        bmp_arr = np.fromstring(signed_ints_arr, dtype=np.uint8)
        bmp_info = bmp.GetInfo()
        pil_im = Image.frombuffer(
            "RGB",
            (bmp_info["bmWidth"], bmp_info["bmHeight"]),
            bmp_arr,
            "raw",
            "BGRX",
            0,
            1,
        )
        buff = BytesIO()
        pil_im.save(buff, format="JPEG")
        img_b64 = b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")

        mfc_dc.DeleteDC()
        dc_obj.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self._hwnd, hwnd_dc)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(bmp.GetHandle())

        return img_b64
```

Variant #2

```
def area_screenshot(self, start: Tuple[int, int], size: Tuple[int, int]) -> str:
        width, height = size[0], size[1]
        x_cord, y_cord = start[0], start[1]

        hwnd_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self._hwnd)
        mfc_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwnd_dc)
        dc_obj = mfc_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()
        bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfc_dc, width, height)

        dc_obj.SelectObject(bmp)
        dc_obj.BitBlt(
            (0, 0), (width, height), mfc_dc, (x_cord, y_cord), win32con.SRCCOPY
        )

        signed_ints_arr = bmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
        bmp_arr = np.fromstring(signed_ints_arr, dtype=np.uint8)
        bmp_info = bmp.GetInfo()
        pil_im = Image.frombuffer(
            "RGB",
            (bmp_info["bmWidth"], bmp_info["bmHeight"]),
            bmp_arr,
            "raw",
            "BGRX",
            0,
            1,
        )
        buff = BytesIO()
        pil_im.save(buff, format="JPEG")
        img_b64 = b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")

        return img_b64
```

Comment: How did you conclude that *ReleaseDC* is the culprit? Those are very different pieces of code.

Comment: I don't think that ReleaseDC is the culprit, I just don't know why to use it if everything works without it, and I want to figure out which option is more correct when to use ReleaseDC and what it is for. But I agree that the option when getting a pixel is not the best. I also wanted to clarify why, when getting the color of a pixel, you need to get a bitmap, maybe it should be removed and only GetDC and ReleaseDC, without creating a bitmap? This is just someone else's code and I want to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation states that [ReleaseDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasedc#remarks) must be called after using `GetWindowDC` or `GetDC`.

> The application must call the `ReleaseDC` function for each call to the
> `GetWindowDC` function and for each call to the `GetDC` function that
> retrieves a common DC.
>
> An application cannot use the ReleaseDC function to release a DC that
> was created by calling the CreateDC function; instead, it must use the
> `DeleteDC` function. ReleaseDC must be called from the same thread that
> called GetDC.

If you don't release it, your program will keep occupying this GDI resource, which will cause memory leaks.

Comment: Leaking the memory is not nearly as bad as leaking the GDI handle. There's a hard limit on the number of [GDI objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects), and its shared between all processes running in the same session.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the clarifications, in general, I realized that in any case, you need to use ReleaseDC, and delete all created dc and objects so that there are no problems in perspective.